# Javascript performance with closure

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

```
var name = function(n) {
    var digits = ['one','two','three','four'];
    return digits[n];
}

var namenew = (function() {
    digits = ['one','two','three','four'];
    return function(n) {
        return digits[n];
    }
}());
```

Both the versions result in the same output, however it is said that the second version is much faster than the first version.

As I understand, first version executes the function everytime where as the second version stores the result of execution. That is what confuses me as a functional/regular OOPS programmer.

How can one save a function with its inner context? What is happening under the hood? Can some one pls clarify?

Comment: It's creating an object that contains the digits list, plus a method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The real answer to that question would be about 3 pages long. But I try to make it as short as possible. ECMA-/Javascript is all about `Execution Contexts` and `Object`. There are three basic types of Context in ECMAscript:  `Global context`, `Function contexts` and `eval contexts`.

Every time you call a function, your engine will spawn it in it's own `function context`. Also, there is a such called `Activation object` created. This mystic object is part of a `function context` which consists out of at least:

- [[Scope chain]]
- Activation object
- "this" context value

There may be more properties on different engines, but these three are required for any implementation of ES. However, back to the topic. If a function context is invoked, all `parent contexts` (or more precisly, the `Activation objects` from the parent contexts) are copied over into the `[[Scope]]` property. You can think of this property like an array, which holds (Activation-) Objects. Now, any function related information is stored in the Activation object (formal parameters, variables, function declarations).

In your example, the `digits` variable is stored in the Activation object for `namenew`. The second when the inner anonymous function is created, it adds that `Activation object` into its `[[Scope]]` propertys. When you call `digits[n]` there, Javascript first tries to find that variable in its **own** Activation object. If that fails, the search goes into the Scopechain. And voila, there we found the variable because we copied the AO from the outer function.

I already wrote too much for a short answer, but to really give a good answer to such a question you have to explain some basic knowledge about ES here. I guess that is just enough to give you an idea what really happens "under the hood" (there is a lot more to know, if you want to read more I'll give you some references).

---

You asked for it, you get it:

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/

Answer (score 9):

The first function recreates `digits` every time it's executed. If it's a large array this is needlessly expensive.

The second function stores `digits` in a context shared only with `namenew`. Every time `namenew` is executed it only performs a single operation: `return digits[n]`.

An example like this wont show any noticeable gains in performance, but with very large arrays/objects/function calls performance will be improved significantly.

In an OOP perspective using a closure in this manner is similar to storing data in a static variable.

---

Don't forget that `namenew` is receiving the *result* of the closure function. The closure itself is only executed *once*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I understand all that you mentioned. What I am looking for is what is happening 'Under the hood'

Comment: IMO from an OOP perspective this type of closure is more like a singleton; it's constructed once, stores its state, and provides access. But both analogies are imperfect. But the question itself could just be summarised as "how does a closure work?" The example distracts from this as the first function should be more like `var digits = ['one','two','three','four']; var name = function(n) { return digits[n]; }` to actually be functionally equivalent. Mentioning, "it is said that the second version is much faster" just confuses this.