# is there a practical difference between the following 2 pieces of code

Tags: javascript

is there any difference between the following peieces of code in javascript:

```
// assuming myModule is an object with some methods
(function(myVar){
    ...
    //using myVar inside this function 
    var b = myVar.getB();
})(myModule);
```

and:

```
// assuming myModule is an object with some methods
(function(){
var myVar = myModule;
...
var b = myVar.getB();
})();
```

in both cases i can assume that by using myVar i am actually using the myModule object.. and as long as myVar is not being redeclared in an inner function inside the self-executing annonymous function - this should be the same, isn't it ?

Comment: The first version adds some flexibility. For example, when you are writing tests, you can pass a mock object as a parameter if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference...

In the first example you define that function having one parameter in the second you're using `myModule` from the context outside the closure (`myModule` have to be defined there).

The first example is more functional. Which means, you can reuse that method anywhere, because it does not depend on its outer context. You could probably outsource that function into a library.

The second example heavily depends on its wrapping function, which can sometimes lead to more difficulty in debugging and avoids reusability. It's like accessing global variables, which in regular you wouldn't wand to do... (which is okay if you are wrapping that variable within an javascript object... it really depends on that specific situation)

Comment: if I outsourced the first piece of code into a library i would STILL have to change the passed parameter if i wanted flexibility . someone using that library would still have to change it from the inside in order to get that flexibility .. so this is not a technical difference, only an architechtural one, at most .. no ? my goal is to understand if there is a technical difference ..

Comment: Yes, but you would just outsource the inner definition of the function... The surrounding "()(myModule)" is just to call that function as closure and should be in the specific code itself and not in the library.

Comment: Furthermore you can say, that the second snippet is a pure closure, where the functional code has dependencies to it's bound context (wrapping java object), while the first snippet's code is encapsulated and just depends on it's parameter (myVar) and could possibly reused... Yes, it is an architectural difference, and therefore a technical difference as well...

Comment: You could also read the following article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614572/javascript-performance-with-closure
That could also help to understand...